# How to create a logical AND with pagination in Angular Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a collection of products in my firestore database. I want the user to be able to filter these products on fields such as color, type and brand. Each product contains a value for each of these fields.

Currently, I've attempted to use the where query to return the collection on the values that would be selected by a user (which works), however I want to implement infinite scoll / pagination so I can limit the number of reads done at once.

My code attempt:

```
  return this.db
  .collection("products", (ref) =>
    ref.where('productName', '==', 'sofa').orderBy('productName').startAfter(lastSeen).limit(batchSize)
  )
  .snapshotChanges();
```

This code of course returns an error as you cannot combine the where with an orderBy / startAfter query.

My question is, how can I adapt this code to use multiple equality where's (I want exact matches, hence not using 'array-contains') that would also allow me to use orderBy so I can add the infinite scroll / limit the number of results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not currently supported for angularfire2.

However, I was able to run the following sample successfully in a testing app using the default Firestore [Web Client Library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore):

```
db.collection('cities')
.where('country','==', "USA")
.where('capital','==', true)
.orderBy("population")
.startAfter(100000)
.limit(2)
.get()
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding - in terms of integrating the above with an Angular app, how is that possible without the use of Angular Fire? Is there some documentation you could link?

Comment: I edited the answer.
Also, see the "Web" examples on [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) page